# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 (Sort Condition)

Tags: java, eclipse, sorting, conditional-statements, bounds

I would like someone to assess this code. It's an insertion sort made in Eclipse. I get this error where java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 whenever I add "=" symbol in the while loop k>=0. If I do remove it, it would run properly but wouldn't give me the expected output of sorting it in ascending order.

For example, if I have values Initial [21, 34, 3, 19, 13] the output would be -> [21, 3, 13, 19, 34].

Logically, having the expression while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k>=0)) is correct arranging it manually, but why does it leave me with that kind of error/exception out of bounds?

```
    int j, k=0, temp, count = 0;
    List<Integer> n = set.getvalues();

    for(j = 1; j < n.size(); j++)
    {
        temp = n.get(j);
        k = j-1;

                while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k >= 0))
                {
                    n.set(k+1, n.get(k));
                    k = k-1;
                    count++;
                }

        n.set(k+1, temp);
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown´?

Comment: In line -> while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k >= 0))

Comment: Twist the statements: while (k>=0 && temp<n.get(k))

Comment: Wow it works! @L33T what's the explanation why it didn't work without exchanging them?

Comment: Put it as an answer with explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that `k >= 0` before attempting to call `n.get(k)`. Attempting to get an element with a negative index doesn't make sense, therefore an `ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException` is thrown.

Reorder

```
while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k >= 0))
```

to

```
while((k >= 0) && (temp < n.get(k)))
```

For `logical and` (`&&`) operations, the expression is evaluated from left to right and will stop evaluation as soon as a `false` is encountered. This is also known as short-circuiting.

Therefore if `k >= 0` evaluates to `false`, `n.get(k)` will not get called and no exception will be thrown.

Comment: Is there any more in depth explanation for this one? Why having to check n.get(k) has to be done after k >= 0?

Comment: @user1868864 Because they are resolved left to right, k >= 0 needs to be checked before accessing the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

As requested the explanation:

```
while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k >= 0))
{
    n.set(k+1, n.get(k));
    k = k-1;
    count++;
}
```

The term (k >= 0) in while((temp < n.get(k)) && (k >= 0)) will be checked after (temp < n.get(k)), as conditional statements are left-to-right resolved. So it does check after already accessing with k = -1, which throws that exception, thats why twisting the statements fixes it.